# Select statement have got error in VB.Net with mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

The error message is also available in another threads but in my case it's different.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. When querying the following select statement. What is the problem inside?

```
 Dim con As New MySqlConnection(ConString)
            Dim sql As String
            Dim idno As Integer
            sql = "select client_id from car_rent where car_id = @carid"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carid", carid.Text.Trim)
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
            idno = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            If (idno > 0) Then
                MsgBox("The Car is already Rented!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Car Rental System")
                Return
            End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch the order of these two lines

```
cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carid", carid.Text.Trim)
```

Also the line in which you execute the command seems to be working because you are using Option Strict Off, and I suggest to change to Option Strict On. In the short term you have to solve many problems but it allows better coding practices

```
 idno = CType(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
```

However, if the command above doesn't find any record matching the parameter passed, ExecuteScalar returns Nothing and so you need to test for this situation

```
Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
if result IsNot Nothing Then

    idno = CType(result, Integer)
```

And, of course, the connection should be opened before, so summarizing everything

```
Dim sql = "select client_id from car_rent where car_id = @carid"
Using con As New MySqlConnection(ConString)
Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
   con.Open()

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carid", carid.Text.Trim)
   Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
   if result IsNot Nothing Then
       Dim idno = CType(result, Integer)
       If (idno > 0) Then
            MsgBox("The Car is already Rented!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Car Rental System")
            Return
       End If
   End If
End Using
End Using
```

Well probably is enough to test for Nothing on the result of ExecuteScalar to take your decision unless you need the idno variable for other purposes.

Comment: I tried using your suggestion steel same problem. The error indicates on **cmd.ExecuteScalar()**

Comment: But can u tell me what is **IsNot Nothing** and what is the secret inside this code?

Comment: As I have said ExecuteScalar could return null (Nothing in Visual Basic), so the [operator IsNot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c.aspx) says, if your return value is not null then you have found a record that matches your request. (and probably its idno is > 0)

Comment: Really in .Net very helpful functions available. It's Ok!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you opening the connection anywhere. use

```
con.open()
```